# How to move camera back on canvas

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am looking for a way to move the camera back with the code that I have here. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I have adjusted `camera.position.set` and added `camera.position.x` parameters.

```js
function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas
  });
  const fov = 45;
  const aspect = 2;
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 100;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 10, 20);
  const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
  controls.target.set(0, 5, 0);
  controls.update();
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('black'); {
    const planeSize = 0;
    const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const texture = loader.load('');
    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    const repeats = planeSize / 2;
    texture.repeat.set(repeats, repeats);
    const planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(planeSize, planeSize);
    const planeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      map: texture,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);
    mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI * -.5;
    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  function frameArea(sizeToFitOnScreen, boxSize, boxCenter, camera) {
    const halfSizeToFitOnScreen = sizeToFitOnScreen * 0.5;
    const halfFovY = THREE.Math.degToRad(camera.fov * .5);
    const distance = halfSizeToFitOnScreen / Math.tan(halfFovY);

    const direction = (new THREE.Vector3())
      .subVectors(camera.position, boxCenter)
      .multiply(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 1))
      .normalize();

    camera.near = boxSize / 100;
    camera.far = boxSize * 100;

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    camera.lookAt(boxCenter.x, boxCenter.y, boxCenter.z);
  }

      const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(root);

      const boxSize = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3()).length();
      const boxCenter = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());

      frameArea(boxSize * 0.5, boxSize, boxCenter, camera);

      controls.maxDistance = boxSize * 10;
      controls.target.copy(boxCenter);
      controls.update();
    });
  }

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render() {
    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). At the moment, your code is extremely ineligible. Make sure to only add the sections of your code that are relevant to the problem you are trying to solve. Preferably dividing them in smaller code blocks.

Comment: I have removed the code that I know is not relevant.

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually asking? You are aware of the position properties of the camera. I believe you can translate the camera as well... camera.translateX( val )

Comment: No worries thank you, I have figured out the issue I was having. I needed to increase the box size using this line of code:
frameArea(boxSize * 0.5, boxSize, boxCenter, camera);
I needed to compute the distance and then move the camera that distance from the center of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question has been resolved.
I needed to increase the box size using this line of code:

frameArea(boxSize * **0.5**, boxSize, boxCenter, camera);

The equations are based off of SOHCAHTOA. I needed to compute the distance and then move the camera that distance from the center of the box.